# Django populate form using Function based view with multiple forms

Tags: python, django, forms, django-views

I'm using Django 2.1 with python 3.6 and postgreSQL.

I have to display 3 different forms in the same template. So I created a view in which I putted the 3 forms, but this doesn't show them populated as if using a CBV with `generic.UpdateView`.

I need to add the current information of the models that are being updated inside each form field.

I also created this because I didn't found a lot of information about how to create a FBV with multiple forms in Django. I imagine that there are few things that are not correct in the view, so all suggestions are welcome.

The view:

```
def project_update_view(request, pk):
    project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)

    if request.method == 'POST':
        general_form = UpdateProjectGeneralForm(request.POST)
        investment_form = UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm(request.POST)
        create_job_form = UpdateProjectAddWorkersForm(request.POST)

        if general_form.is_valid():
            general_form.instance.user = request.user
            general_form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Project Updated'
            general_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Project updated!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

        if investment_form.is_valid():
            investment_form.instance.user = request.user
            investment_form.instance.history_change_reason = 'Investor Details Updated'
            investment_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Investment details updated!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

        if create_job_form.is_valid():
            create_job_form.instance.project = project
            create_job_form.instance.history_change_reason = 'New Job Added'
            create_job_form.save()
            messages.success(request, 'Job created!')
            return HttpResponseRedirect(request.path_info)

    else:
        general_form = UpdateProjectGeneralForm()
        investment_form = UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm()
        create_job_form = UpdateProjectAddWorkersForm()

    return render(request, 'webplatform/project_edit.html', {
        'general_form': general_form,
        'investment_form': investment_form,
        'create_job_form': create_job_form,
        'project': project,
    })
```

The forms: (To evade extra code, I just put one form. The others have the same structure)

```
class UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Project
        fields = ('investor_details', 'investment_percentage', 'investment_amount')
        widgets = {
            'investor_details': SummernoteWidget(attrs={'summernote': {
                'placeholder': 'Add some details for the future investors here...'}}),
        }

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        # first call parent's constructor
        super(UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # there's a `fields` property now
        self.fields['investment_amount'].required = True
        self.fields['investment_percentage'].required = True
        self.fields['investor_details'].required = True
```

The template: (this is one of the forms, but all of them follow the same structure)

```
<form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ investment_form.investment_amount|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            {{ investment_form.investment_percentage|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>
        <div class="col-12">
            {{ investment_form.investor_details|as_crispy_field }}
        </div>

    </div>
    <button type="submit" name="investment_form" class="btn btn-primary">Update investment details
    </button>
</form>
```

Comment: I don't think it can ever work to have separate `<form>` elements, because submitting a form necessarily reloads the page (assuming no `action` attribute pointing to a different endpoint) and sends just the data in that form as the POST payload. So whenever you submit one form, the `request.POST` only includes the data from that form, and anything else is getting lost (and therefore not populated). There's no reason why you can't have multiple Django forms as part of just a single html form, with one submit button, and a view function which processes them all.

Comment: you are right, there is no problem with the submit buttons, I'll edit my question to do focus on the population part. Thank you!

Comment: Do you want to save only if all forms are valid, or partial saves are also welcome? One thing that you definietly could/should do is to pass to your forms (if they are for `Project` model) your instance as `instance=project`.

Comment: I want to save only one at once. The only thing I want to do now is populate all of them with their respective current information.

Comment: @mfrackowiak I checked today again what you where telling me to do and now I get it, sorry. You where absolutely right! instancing the project on the form is what I needed. I'm gonna add the solution to the post and close it. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As @mfackowiak said on the comments, the problem is that my forms are not instanced with the model I want to edit, so I just had to change this:

```
general_form = UpdateProjectGeneralForm(request.POST)
investment_form = UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm(request.POST)
create_job_form = UpdateProjectAddWorkersForm(request.POST)
```

for this:

```
general_form = UpdateProjectGeneralForm(request.POST, instance=project)
investment_form = UpdateProjectInvestorDetailsForm(request.POST, instance=project)
create_job_form = UpdateProjectAddWorkersForm(request.POST)
```

As an extra, I saw that I can call the object with a `get_object_or_404` so I use it on the first line and from this:

```
 project = Project.objects.get(pk=pk)
```

I got this:

```
 project = get_object_or_404(Project, pk=pk)
```